# How margin text from left of element?

Tags: html, css

There is `span` block with icon inside:

```
<span><i></i>Text</span>
```

Icon has CSS:

```
i {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
}
```

If `text` is long it wraps to next line under icon `i`.

How to wrap text with margin-left: width of icon

I have now this:

```
Icon - Text he
re
```

But I need:

```
Icon - Text he
       re
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Absolute positioning

```css
span {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 1em;
}

i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<span><i>I</i>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, quam.</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can indent the `span` right and the icon left:

```css
i {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   margin-left: -20px;
   background: yellow;
}

span {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 40px;
   margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<span><i></i>Text here</span>
```

Comment: There are no divs in the example

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox:

```css
span {
  display: flex;
}

i {
  margin-right: 4px;
  min-width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<span><i></i>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </span>
```